# Select - Order By word in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to order by Word in MySQL?

For example:

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `batch` = 'something' AND outcome in ('Business','Professional', 'Consumer')
```

I want to get a list of rows in order: Business, Professional and then Consumer rather than alphabet order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `table` 
WHERE `batch` = 'something' 
       AND outcome in ('Business','Professional', 'Consumer')
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN outcome  = 'Business'     THEN 1
        WHEN outcome  = 'Professional' THEN 2
        WHEN outcome  = 'Consumer'     THEN 3
        ELSE 4
   END
```

Comment: Very nice! Never knew `CASE WHEN` would work after `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

you can union each one in specifically.. try this.

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `batch` = 'something' AND outcome = 'Business'

UNION

SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `batch` = 'something' AND outcome = 'Professional'

UNION

SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `batch` = 'something' AND outcome = 'Consumer'
```